# Single bool must queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, booleanquery

Does wrapping single Elasticsearch queries in bool must queries change search results, or are the following two queries identical (both in terms of how elasticsearch processes them and what the outcome is)?

single `query_string` query (no `bool` query as wrapper):

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : { "query" : "My query string" }
}}
```

`bool` query that wrapps a single `query_string` query:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : { "query" : "My query string" }
}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are exactly semantically the same and will produce the same results.

It's worth noting, though, that a `bool` query only makes sense if there are more than one clause, otherwise it's useless to specify it.

Comment: thanks. Yes you are right, but my program automatically adds multiple must clauses to the bool query and i wanted to be sure that a single must clause behaves identical to a single query without bool wrapper.